# check if localStorage.removeItem() was successful

Tags: javascript, local-storage

If I remove an item using `localStorage.removeItem("key");` is there any way I can check if the removal was successful or not? Something like a callback or promise?

Right now I am doing like this:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("key"))
    localStorage.removeItem("key");
else
    console.log("Error");
```

Is this the right way to do it or could this be done in a "better" way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `removeItem()` call does not return any indication of failure<sup>1</sup> of *any* sort (excerpt taken from [a recent editor's draft of the W3C web storage specification](http://w3c.github.io/webstorage/), with my emphasis):

> The `removeItem(key)` method must cause the key/value pair with the given key to be removed from the list associated with the object, if it exists. ***If no item with that key exists, the method must do nothing.***

Hence, the only way to tell if the key was an *actual* removal (as opposed to the "do nothing" action in the second sentence above) is to check it first.

You should almost certainly use explicit checking of the `getItem()` return value against `null` (with `===` of course) but that doesn't change the fact that you can't detect failure with `removeItem()` itself<sup>1</sup>.

Of course, if you're worried about peppering your code with these snippets, you're quite able to define a function to do the heavy lifting for you, something like:

```
function removeExistingItem(key) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(key) === null)
        return false;
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    return true;
}
```

and then call it with the more succinct:

```
if (! removeExistingItem("key"))
    console.log("Error");
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is based on "failure" being defined as the key not existing (as seems to be the definition you're using in the question). In reality, `removeItem()` *cannot* fail simply because it will do nothing in the case where the item does not exist (see inset above).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

A more accurate check will be as below, else if the value of the `key` was `""`(empty string) then it will fail

```
if (localStorage.getItem("key") !== null) {
    localStorage.removeItem("key");
} else {
    console.log("Error");
}
```

[Storage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) will return `null` if the key is not found

Comment: yeah thanks, however I suppose you mean if(localStorage.getItem("key") !== null)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue today [06-23-2019], and adjusted @paxdiablo's answer to add a few more fail-safes to the solution. I really hope my version helps someone else save the time and headache I went through:

```
/* Conditional Function supplements localStorage.removeItem(...) to return a [Boolean] 'success' or 'failure' value. [BEGIN] */

if (typeof removeLocalStorageItem !== 'function')
    {
        function removeLocalStorageItem(key) 
            {
                if (typeof (Storage) !== 'undefined')
                    {
                        if (localStorage.getItem(key) === null)
                            {
                                return false;
                            };

                        localStorage.removeItem(key);

                        if (localStorage.getItem(key) === null)
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                return false;
                            };
                    }
                else
                    {
                        return false;
                    };
            };
    };

/* Conditional Function supplements localStorage.removeItem(...) to return a [Boolean] 'success' or 'failure' value. [END] */
```